# Android Studio Unknown attribute in xml and Namespace not found

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I recently got this warning in `Layout` and manifest files.
I have attached those images below just check those in case for further clarification.

The problem is I'm getting Namespace " is not bound warning and I cannot use the autocomplete code for xml files which can be generally used in android studio.Please help for this issue.
The unknown xml attribute warning is displayed for each and every android attribute.

[image: http://i39.tinypic.com/2rr55k1.png]

[image: http://i41.tinypic.com/2ns2s0w.png]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"

              >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blue"

            >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="15"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 42):

It is very simple. Delete .caches file:

1. Just close your AS.
2. Go to .AndroidStudio3.2 folder.
3. Delete the Caches file (path is: `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\caches`)
4. Restart your AS.
5. Enjoy.

NB: **This Solution is for Android Studio 4+**

**if you are using Android Studio 3+ then delete cache from the following path**

C:\Users\user.AndroidStudio3.x\system\caches

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me!

Comment: This actually what did the trick for me so thanks :)

Comment: Android Studio 2020.3 Arctic Fox has this folder in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\caches`

Comment: @PhpXp But I was unable to find this path  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\caches

Comment: @ABHIMANGALMS try this path: `%localappdata%\Google`

Comment: @PhpXp Yes, I got it because of you. 
I just updated the answer. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 25):

Ran into the same issue. I think that there's some specific bug related to this for  Android Studio 3.2. My solution on Windows was to delete everything withing the cache/ folder in the .AndroidStudio3.2/ folder.

I tried everything that other's mentioned, sync gradle files, invalidate cache, removed the whole project and added it again. The only thing that worked for me was reinstalling the Android Studio. The second time that happened to me I decided to look for a better solution than reinstalling the whole Android Studio. Started playing with the cache files and figured out that deleting everything under the cache/ folder in the configuration folder of the Android Studio solved the problem.

Comment: Kudos! You saved me a reinstall. I had tried everything else and nothing worked but this.

Comment: You are a life saviour . I was about to reinstall android studio. THANKS !!

Comment: Is this legit working? I tried to delete and before i would, the system found around 1.8gb of data. Should i really do it?

Comment: @Pointyhat I'm not really sure if we are talking about the same folder, move all the contents of your cache folder, to a backup folder just in case. I did that when I was trying all this.

Comment: It really helped. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 18):

This is problem with Android studio caches.

most probably syncing the project with gradle files will help

[image: re sync from here]

If no, you can manually delete cached files located on $HOME/.AndroidStudio3.2/system/caches and rebuild your project.

**UPDATE**:
Gradle sync cache isses fixed in android studio 3.5 version. Update android studio to latest version can help.

Answer (score 2):

**100% Working**

Do this two steps:

1. Go to folder where you android studio caches are located. 
   I have android studio 3.6.3
   For me it's `C:\Users\User_folder\.AndroidStudio3.6\system\caches`.
2. Go to the folder where you android studio projects are located.
   Open the project >then .idea folder and delete the caches.
   For me its `C:\Users\User_folder\AndroidStudioProjects\Project_name\.idea\caches`.

Answer (score 2):

For **Android Studio 4. +**

The [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54070040/7418129) is deprecated as Android studio Arctic fox released.
Cause, the specified path is unable to find.

So do the updated workaround.

Close the Android Studio

1. Delete 3 folders in the this directory C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle

   a. caches

   b. daemon

   c. wrapper
2. Invalidate cache in Android Studio and Restart it.

Answer (score 1):

To "Sync Project with Gradle files" you don't have to change anything on your file. If you're on a Mac you just cmd + fn + F9 or cmd + shift + a (search action and type what's between double quotes). There's also a beautiful icon for that on Android Studio.