# Android Studio layout Error : Unknown attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Android Studio Code Completion seems not working on xml and also it doesn't recognize any xml attribute except the attrs on Android support v7 views. 
Screenshot:

[image]

my views that is from android.support.design.v7 display correctly:

[image]

Comment: make sure closing TextView as </TextView>

Comment: this is a piece of my code just for example. i got this error on all xml files

Comment: have you added  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` on top of your layout xml files ?

Comment: added. Nothing changed. please help.

Comment: my views that is from android.support.design.v7 display correctly.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jxht9m67oanjftp/Screenshot%202015-09-20%2011.07.35.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are Android Studio then go to tools and then Android then click on build with gradle, it will solve the error. I encountered it too.

> Tools->Android->Build with Gradle

Comment: I didn't try this, but it seems it'd do the job.

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue for a while and tried all the "solutions" provided;

- Sync Gradle files.
- Invalidate cache.
- Removed and re-add project.
- Reinstall Android Studio.

Nothing worked, until **I came across this answer** (by 4gus71n) **which has worked** for me every time this rather rare, but annoying issue has presented itself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53160674/5692877

In my case I;

1. Closed Android Studio.
2. Cleared the contents of the `C:\Users\MyUsername\.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches\` directory.
3. Relaunched Android Studio.

Worked a treat!

Comment: Provided link in this answer really worked. All other methods didn't work for me.