# Android Studio suggestion in xml not showing for a specific project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio version 3.5.1,  and for all other projects it works fine, but for a specific project the xml suggestions are not showing. I have already tried by invalidating caches, deleting `.idea` folder, but the result remained the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".xyz">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue a while back and was able to fix it by following these steps;

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Delete the contents of the `C:\Users\{MyUsername}\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches\` directory.
3. Re-launch Android Studio.

This should have things working for you again. I hope that helps!

***Note***: my answer here is a slight revision of a [prior answer I'd provided to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32676208/android-studio-layout-error-unknown-attribute/53842237#53842237). I had tried all the other recommendations that you've mentioned in your question and none bar the one I've included above seemed to work for me.

Comment: That’s excellent news @ShubhasishRoutray ! Do you mind accepting my answer?