# Unknown attribute android:layout_width, layout_height, id, gravity, layout_gravity, padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml, android-layoutparams

- Getting Unknown attribute error on all android tag.
- In layout XML, Auto suggestion is not showing all attributes (like layout_width, layout_height, orientation, orientation & all others android attributes.)

Here is a Snap shot

[image]

[image]
Things i have done to resolve this issue.

- Clean Build & Rebuild
- Deleted .idea file
- Invalidated Caches/ Restart.. option
- Turn On Power Save Mode.

SDk is up to date.

In App Level Gridle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.abhishek.ondemandservice"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Application level Gride.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2'`

Comment: why do i use older version if it works perfect in other systems and it's not working that way.

Comment: You might want to accept one of the answers if they fixed your issue

Comment: This worked for me
check this llink
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52965770/8648075

Answer (score 56):

Just go to Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: Just to add - in Android Studio 3.1 there's a button called "Sync project with gradle files" between "revert" and "avd manager" buttons in a right corner of a toolbar.

Comment: And in 3.1.2 it's far left, between "Save All" and "Sync with File System".

Answer (score 51):

The only thing that worked for me was cleaning the following folders:

```
c:\Users\<user>\.gradle\caches\
c:\Users\<user>\.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches\
```

Android Studio will just redownload the libraries and caches them which will enable everything back to normal.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53053438/7515903

Credits: @alexuz

Comment: I tries everything everyone suggested, nothing helped. I deleted everything inside c:\Users\<user>\.gradle\caches\
and it fixed it (I took it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/53053438/7515903, but I didn't need to delete the other suggestion)

Comment: Similar solution here (to a different problem) that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52687462/1617737

Comment: This solved my problem. But not the first time I have to solve this such a problem by literally rebuilding my entire project. Almost every AS update is the same. Wish iOS was bigger so I could just switch to that. sad

Answer (score 16):

To fix, change something in your gradle file, then sync gradle again. This worked for me.

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47500156/5673746

Comment: Worked like magic.. Been stuck on this for almost three days! Thanks a lot.. I wish you less bugs!

Answer (score 11):

I tried:

- Removing the build folders
- Cleaning the project
- Sync Project with Gradle Files

But nothing worked. Finally using **File > Invalidate caches** fixed the error.

Comment: Funny.  For me, invalidate caches didn't work but sync with Gradle did.  Guess there are multiple potential causes to this issue.

Comment: Sometimes just closing ad reopening Android Studio can fix this type of issues.

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work. I did a similar thins: deleted C:\Users\.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches. 
See stackoverflow.com/a/52965770/8648075 as @M.J.M suggested.

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue, but after a reinstall of visual studio, so what helped for me on Android studio 3.2, was to go and upgrade the target version to 28 and compile version 28. Was at version 27 before.

I had to upgrade these packages as well

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0'
```

After Gradle had synced then it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

**Any of these ways will possibly fix your problem (unknown attribute android:layout-width)**

1. Sync project with Gradle file (File -> Sync project with Gradle files)
2. Invalidate cache and restart (File -> Invalidate cache and restart -> Invalidate and restart)
3. Delete .gradle and .idea file from the project folder and rebuild the project.
4. Delete caches folder from Android studio (.AndroidStudio3.2 -> system -> caches)

Answer (score 5):

I too encountered this..

1. Just delete the .idea folder that is in the project location
2. Build > Clean Project
3. Then change something in the app level gradle

Then android studio will ask you to sync the project. Go ahead and sync, the problem will be gone

Answer (score 3):

if non of above answers dosn't work do these steps:

1. first close android studio.
2. than just go to windows>User    **or**     AppData>local>
   and delete androidstudio last version  folder
3. reopen androidstuduio and set default settings

Answer (score 2):

In my case **none** of the above solutions **worked** for me, **but changing** the `minSdkVersion` to a **higher** version and doing a gradle sync after that did the trick, maybe this would be useful to somebody.

Answer (score 2):

If you're facing this issue only for a few of the attributes like android:text or android:layout_margin, etc, check if your compileSdkVersion is 33 in gradle, and try downgrading it to 32 in build.gradle(:app)

Answer (score 1):

None of the existing suggestion works for me. I solved this issue by reinstalling Android Studio. Really weird.

Comment: After trying everything else on this list, my only solution was to reinstall from scratch. What a waste of time!

Answer (score 1):

I had to

1. Delete Android SDK from AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
2. Reinstall Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `compileSdkVersion`/`buildToolsVersion`/`targetSdkVersion` from 30 to 29 in `build.gradle` and the problem disappeared for me.

Comment: I had the same issue with 33.  I fell back to 32 and it's working again.

Comment: Hi For me also same issue happened, So changed  compile and target sdk versions from 33 to 32 then everything is working fine, But still I do't understand why android studio is not able to synch app properly with sdk 33.

Answer (score 1):

I´ve tryed all the solutions but the only thing that worked for me was 4gus71n's answer.

Deleting the **C:\Users.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches** folder solved my problem.

Link to his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53160674/6568421

Answer (score 0):

I just changed my android SDK path and restart android studio->set new SDK path
it working

Answer (score 0):

Just update your android studio:
Help -> Check for Updates..