# Unknown attribute android

Tags: android

[image]

Getting Unknown attribute error on all android tag.

In layout XML, Auto suggestion is not showing all attributes (like layout_width, layout_height, orientation, orientation & all others android attributes.)

Things i have done to resolve this issue.

Clean Build & Rebuild
Deleted .idea file
Invalidated Caches/ Restart.. option
Turn On Power Save Mode.
SDk is up to date.

Unknown attribute android:orientation less. (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection highlights unknown XML attributes in Android resource files and `AndroidManifest.xml`

currently using :

```
 Android studio 3.2.1
 targetSdkVersion 27
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'
 build:gradle:3.2.1
```

I tried with deleting .idea in the path and invalidate cache and restart ,synching the gradle

Comment: Have you check if you have a correct `AndroidManifest.xml`  xml structure?

Comment: yes i checked with all posiibilities

Comment: Try checking if Android plugins is enabled in your setting.

Comment: yeah checked,its already enabled

Comment: Try moving your project to a path which doesn't have a space (`  `) in it.

Comment: i got a solution by uninstalling adroid studio and changing the sdk path

Comment: Can you post the build output where the error is displayed? Your screenshot is not of great use without that

Comment: while building it will not show anything,after that in XML Getting Unknown attribute error on all android tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown attribute android:layout\_width, layout\_height, id, gravity, layout\_gravity, padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308735/unknown-attribute-androidlayout-width-layout-height-id-gravity-layout-gravi)

Answer (score 43):

got the same issue recently with Windows7 and Android studio 3.2.1. what's actually helped is clean up of the following folders:

```
c:\Users\<user>\.gradle\caches\
c:\Users\<user>\.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches\
```

Comment: it was solution in my case, before this I tried all possible ways but nothing helped

Comment: and one more thing,delete the wrapper gradle-version-all and again rebuild the application..

Comment: It works. In the end, I just need to sync gradle with project and click the hammer button.

Comment: This is the only solution that's worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this should be marked as **right & accepted answer** among all others answers for this issue on **S.O**.

Comment: Where can we find the folders in Linux distribution?

Answer (score 1):

**100% Working**

These two steps will solve.

Do this two steps:
1.Go to folder where you android studio caches are located. I have android studio 3.6.3 For me it's "C:\Users\Lenovo.AndroidStudio3.6\system\caches"
2.Go to the folder where you android studio projects are located. Open the project >then .idea folder and delete the caches. For me its "C:\Users\Lenovo\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictionary.idea\caches"