# Abnormal behavior in Android Studio

Tags: android

Getting error in Android Studio in an existing project while adding any new file there. Without adding any change the code is running perfectly. I have tried with the following solution :
c:\Users\.gradle\caches\ 
c:\Users\.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches\
from this below link: 
[Unknown attribute android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854173/unknown-attribute-android?answertab=votes#tab-top)
but it did not work me. Any help in this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: whats the error?

Answer (score 0):

My first troubleshooting task would be to try Invalidating Caches and Restart?

On Linux, that is under File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart

Not sure of the exact location on Windows, but it should be in a similar location.

It might help garner more answers if you added more specifics about your issue in your OP.