# Unknow attributes in xml files after migrating to Androidx

Tags: android, androidx

I migrated to AndroidX via **Refactor** - **Migrate to AndroidX**

Now Android Studio highlights most attributes in the layouts files as Unknown

I abbreviated the code below to show only some of the unknown attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" (Unknown)
    android:clipToPadding="true" (Unknown)
    android:scrollbars="none" (Unknown)

<LinearLayout
    android:paddingTop="20dp" (Unknown)
    android:paddingBottom="20dp" (Unknown)

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" (Unknown)
        android:paddingStart="20dp" (Unknown)
        android:paddingEnd="20dp" (Unknown)
        android:text="Some Text" (Unknown)
```

In gradle.properties I have

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

In build.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
```

I tried

- Sync Project with Gradle files
- I synced build.gradle
- Invalidate Cach / Restart
- Clean Project followed by Rebuild Project
- I deleted .idea folder followed by Clean & Rebuild project

**Nothing worked**

Comment: sometimes it can be bug of android studio; does your app compile and run ?

Comment: Yes! It compiles and runs normally in debug mode and it generated an apk.

Comment: @Zain The main issue for me that it doesn't provide intellisense when I'm creating a tag. If I write android: it doesn't offer the attributes.

Comment: Try to close and then reimport the project rather than just invalidate and restart, instead of reopening it from the `File -> Open Recent`, click `File -> Open` and then import the project again. A lot of times that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to clean below cache folders to give a change to re-download libraries

```
c:\Users\<user>\.gradle\caches\
c:\Users\<user>\.AndroidStudio3.x\system\caches\
```

Sources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854173/unknown-attribute-android/53053438#53053438), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308735/unknown-attribute-androidlayout-width-layout-height-id-gravity-layout-gravi#answer-53067664)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem some days back; Cleaning the C:\Users.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches also did not worke for me. Fixed it with completly reinstalling Android Studio.