# It doesn't unknown some attributes in AndroidManifest.xml for Android SDK API 33

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-api-levels

I created a new project use API 33 but some field is not found. While `API 32` also finds it without issue. It gives a warning when I open it with `API 33`.

`buid.gradle(My Application)`:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

`build.gradle(:app)`:

```kotlin
android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.halil.ozel.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

[image]

I searched for the problem but couldn't find a solution. If anyone has had this problem or has solved it, I would like your help.

Comment: I have the same problem but no solution either.
Possible duplicate: [Android 33 - issues in manifest and layout files in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72664051/android-33-issues-in-manifest-and-layout-files-in-android-studio)

Comment: I also want to add the issue here, the android:id, android:layout_width, android:layout_height and others, are not showing on tips suggestion. I was force to downgrade from api level 33 to api level 32, so that I can code properly and faster.

Comment: I've found a solution in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240303/14143986). You need to upgrade to Android Studio Electric Eel and upgrade AGP to 7.4.0-alpha09.