# Unknown Attribute Android: error on Android STUDIO 3.2.1

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-studio-3.2

Things i have done to resolve this issue:

- Clean Build & Rebuild
- Deleted .idea file
- Invalidated Caches/ Restart.. option
- Turn On Power Save Mode.
- SDk is up to date.
- Sync Project with Gradle Files done.
- Reinstall Android Studio done
- recreate new project done
- changed something in app Gradle file and synced the project again
- android studio old version change also not help
- Intellij shows to reset to default namespace, it will delete android namespace..
  (In Project, Layout file corrections not reflecting into app)

Android Studio Version

[image: X]

Error Image

[image: X]

gradle image

[image: X]

Intelij Solution

[image: X]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown attribute android:layout\_width, layout\_height, id, gravity, layout\_gravity, padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35308735/unknown-attribute-androidlayout-width-layout-height-id-gravity-layout-gravi)

Comment: Share your gradle dependencies

Comment: Please don't add text as images

Answer (score 20):

**This worked for me**

Close Android studio
Delete all files from

- C:\Users\.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches
- C:\Users\.AndroidStudio3.2\config   //not importent

start android studio

Comment: I deleted only system\caches and it worked for me. Android studio 3.2, gradle 3.2.1.

Comment: deleting only system\cache solved my problem Android Studio 4.0.1 gradle 6.1.1

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same issue. Seems to be something specifically related to Android Studio 3.2. My solution on Windows was to delete everything withing the cache/ folder in the .AndroidStudio3.2/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happen for **Android studio Cache & History**.

Firstly In android studio go `File -> Close Project` and **Exit** Android Studio.

Then Delete below 2 Folders:

- C:\Users\user-name.AndroidStudio3.X\system\caches
- C:\Users\user-name.AndroidStudio3.X\config\terminal\history `(optional)`

**Open the Android Studio and Enjoy**!

Answer (score 0):

Complete uninstall Android Studio (including system and cache files) and Reinstalling clears my bug...