# Android Studio - Unrecognized state_cheked attribute in selector

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Android Studio and Kotlin and I have an interesting problem.

My Android Studio doesn't recognize some attributes. I couldn't find any answer for this.

Neither updating Android Studio nor syncing project with Gradle Files helped.

For example, in my selector, the attributes `state_cheked` and `state_pressed` don't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home22"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home22" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home" />

</selector>
```

The error I get is `Unknown attribute android:state_checked`.

Glad for any help, thanks.

Comment: Do you have same issue in layout files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's a cache problem, try these different solutions

[Android Studio layout Error : Unknown attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53790925/9420348)

[Unknown Attribute Android: error on Android STUDIO 3.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47809896/9420348)

[Android Studio layout Error : Unknown attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48808383/9420348)