# Unknown Android XML attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

First, I really dont know wth goin on with android studio ver 3.2.1. I got too much bullshit errors after update this version. Funny thing is i do nothing. After update, everything is fine, but when i restart IDE. everything go wrong.

I tried clear caches, re-install Android Studio, Invalidate Caches, Re-sync project with Gradle, clean project, re-build project. But, nothing change. So, i hope someone can help me. Thanks so much!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these:

Method 1:

1. Delete the .idea folder that is in the project location
2. Build > Clean Project
3. Then change something in the app level gradle

Then android studio will ask you to sync the project. Go ahead and sync, the problem will be gone
Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47825463/10471480

Method 2:
Try cleaning up of the following folders:
`c:\Users\<user>\.gradle\caches\`
`c:\Users\<user>\.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches\`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, i believe method 2 its true solution. And, thanks you again.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bro. Saved me a lot of trouble I was going to create a new project. The second method worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**100% Working**

Do this two steps:

1.Go to folder where you android studio caches are located. I have android studio 3.6.3 For me it's "C:\Users\Lenovo.AndroidStudio3.6\system\caches"

2.Go to the folder where you android studio projects are located. Open the project >then .idea folder and delete the caches. For me its "C:\Users\Lenovo\AndroidStudioProjects\MyDictionary.idea\caches"