# Unknown attribute for known attributes in xml files

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-xml

I recently installed Android Studio on my Desktop running Ubuntu 17.10. However, when I open any Android Studio Project or even create a new Project, while editing XML files, it wrongly displays an "unknown attribute" error. 
Normally, I wouldn't care, but this causes Android Studio to not give any suggestions for attributes which I need. 
What I've tried: 
Invalidating cache
Deleting the .iml file and rebuilding project
Rebuilding and cleaning project several times
Deleting gradle's cache
Updating Android Studio (Current Release is Android Studio 3.1)
Here is a screenshot of what's happening[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try doing a gradle sync. It should resolve the problem
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I´ve tryed all the solutions but the only thing that worked for me was **4gus71n**'s answer.

Deleting the **C:\Users.AndroidStudio3.2\system\caches** folder solved my problem.

Link to his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53160674/6568421

Answer (score 0):

Use project's SDK not Android's SDK. You can edit SDK Location in local.properties file

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issues and all the above also did not worked for me.

If all else failed, do a clean install of android studio. You need to do a clean installation because if you just uninstall and install again, some of the files still remains in your system. It did not work for me when i just uninstall and install android studio. The clean install worked for me and I believe it should solve most of the problems.

I faced this error probably because i installed an entire android project but I am not very sure what is the exact error that caused this problem.

For clean installation, you can look at this links for windows and mac

[How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)

[How to completely uninstall Android Studio on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)