# Android studio XML autocomplete not working properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

so today I stared at the code when suddenly XML editor (autocomplete) stop working properly. The problem is that when I type the first letter of some element it gives me a proper suggestion but when I start typing other letters it just stuck with the first one and when I confirm the suggestion it gives me 2 words, the first one is the world I type first and the second is the correct one.
[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPAUc.png]

Comment: Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370599/android-studio-auto-complete-and-other-features-not-working

Comment: Do [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54070040/7418129) to solve that issue. Happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

It is very simple. Delete .caches file:

**For Android Studio 4+**

1. Just close your AS.
2. Go to AndroidStudio2020.3 folder.
3. Delete the Caches file (path is: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\caches)
4. Restart your AS.
5. Enjoy.

**For Android Studio 3+**

if you are using *Android Studio 3+* then delete cache from the following path

C:\Users\user\AndroidStudio3.x\system\caches

Comment: thanks a lot I didn't know the path (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2020.3\caches)  you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

I have tried different things(deleting .idea folder and .iml files from the project, invalidate cache and restart the Android Studio) nothing worked.

Finally, I close the Android Studio and navigate to android studio installation directory(i.e C:\Users\Your Username.AndroidStudio3.3\system) delete the Cache folder, run the android studio and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue, because of my Android Studio version

**Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022**

Try to update compile SDK to 31, hope it will get fixed.

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

...
}
```

Also check the ViewModel and appcompat version also, they should be matching the SDK version.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
```