# Unknown attribute android:layout , No auto suggestion in XML android

Tags: android, xml, attributes, autosuggest, unknown-host

```
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPostComment"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:paddingRight="8dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:onClick="@{(view)-> CommentListActivity.onPostComment()}"
                android:foreground="android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_post_comment_96px" />
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Unknown attribute android:layout , No auto suggestion in XML android

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. Delete .caches file:

1. Just close your AS.
2. Go to .AndroidStudio3.2 folder.
3. Delete the Caches file **(path is: C:\ Users \ user \ .AndroidStudio4 \system)**
4. Restart your AS.
5. Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

to fix this you need synchronize your project with gradle file.you can do this by clicking the "synch project with gradle file" button on top right corner.or you can get help here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53160674/10687310